# C++11 does not deduce type when std::function or lambda functions are involved

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

When I define this function,

```
template<class A>
set<A> test(const set<A>& input) {
    return input;
}
```

I can call it using `test(mySet)` elsewhere in the code without having to explicitly define the template type. However, when I use the following function:

```
template<class A>
set<A> filter(const set<A>& input,function<bool(A)> compare) {
    set<A> ret;
    for(auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++) {
        if(compare(*it)) {
            ret.insert(*it);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

When I call this function using `filter(mySet,[](int i) { return i%2==0; });`
I get the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘filter(std::set&, main()::)’

However, all of these versions *do* work:

```
std::function<bool(int)> func = [](int i) { return i%2 ==0; };
set<int> myNewSet = filter(mySet,func);

set<int> myNewSet = filter<int>(mySet,[](int i) { return i%2==0; });

set<int> myNewSet = filter(mySet,function<bool(int)>([](int i){return i%2==0;}));
```

Why is c++11 unable to guess the template type when I put the lambda function directly inside the expression without directly creating a `std::function`?

**EDIT:**

Per advice of Luc Danton in the comments, here is an alternative to the function I had earlier that does not need the templates to be passed explicitly.

```
template<class A,class CompareFunction>
set<A> filter(const set<A>& input,CompareFunction compare) {
    set<A> ret;
    for(auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++) {
        if(compare(*it)) {
            ret.insert(*it);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This can be called by `set<int> result = filter(myIntSet,[](int i) { i % 2 == 0; });` without needing the template.

The compiler can even guess the return types to some extent, using the new decltype keyword and using the new function return type syntax. Here is an example that converts a set to a map, using one filtering function and one function that generates the keys based on the values:

```
template<class Value,class CompareType,class IndexType>
auto filter(const set<Value>& input,CompareType compare,IndexType index) -> map<decltype(index(*(input.begin()))),Value> {
    map<decltype(index(*(input.begin()))),Value> ret;
    for(auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++) {
        if(compare(*it)) {
            ret[index(*it)] = *it;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It can also be called without using the template directly, as

```
map<string,int> s = filter(myIntSet,[](int i) { return i%2==0; },[](int i) { return toString(i); });
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you do realize that your `filter` is essentially equivalent to a non-generic version of `std::copy_if`, don't you?

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of std::copy_if, thank you for pointing that out. However, this is part of a larger group of 4 functions, one which converts set => map while filtering and I don't see a way to implement that with copy_if and allow the user to produce keys using the values in the set. For consistency in usage, I am opting to do it this way.

Comment: For the record, if you want to accept a functor it's usually idiomatic to make it a general template parameter, i.e. `template<typename A, typename Predicate> set<A> filter(set<A> const& input, Predicate compare);`. As you've just witnessed, `std::function` doesn't work to document that the passed predicate should have a signature matching `bool(A)`; there are other ways to do that. Furthermore there are *other* disadvantages in using `std::function` as a function argument.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The issue is on the nature of lambdas. They are function objects with a fixed set of properties according to the standard, but they are *not* a function. The standard determines that lambdas can be converted into `std::function<>` with the exact types of arguments and, if they have no state, function pointers.

But that does not mean that a lambda is a `std::function` nor a function pointer. They are unique types implementing `operator()`.

Type deduction, on the other hand, will only deduce exact types, with no conversions (other than const/volatile qualifications). Because the lambda is not a `std::function` the compiler cannot deduce the type in the call: `filter(mySet,[](int i) { return i%2==0; });` to be any `std::function<>` instantiation.

As of the other examples, in the first one you convert the lambda to the function type, and then pass that. The compiler can deduce the type there, as in the third example where the `std::function` is an rvalue (temporary) of the same type.

If you provide the instantiating type `int` to the template, second working example, deduction does not come into play the compiler will use the type and then convert the lambda to the appropriate type.

Comment: Note that it's not the lambda that performs the conversion to `std::function`, it's `std::function` that accepts anything that is callable.

Comment: Type deduction will also do base-type "conversions" to be complete.

Comment: It can be made to work by disabling deduction for the `compare` arg. We can do this with this signature: `template<class A>
set<A> filter(const set<A>& input
        ,typename NoOp<function<bool(A)> >::type compare
        )`  where `Noop` is defined as `template <typename T>
struct NoOp { 
    typedef T type;
};`

Comment: ... this allows `A` to be deduced by the first arg, then used as-is for the `compare` arg.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid That's a nice solution, but I don't want to introduce a `NoOp` struct very time I need this. Do you happen to know if such a `NoOp` type is available in modern C++ standards as part of STL? It seems useful.

Answer (score 19):

Forget about your case. as that is too complex for analysis.

Take this simple example:

```
 template<typename T>
 struct X 
 {
     X(T data) {}
 };

 template<typename T>
 void f(X<T> x) {}
```

Now call `f` as:

```
 f(10);
```

Here you might be tempted to think that `T` will be deduced to `int` **and** therefore, the above function call should work. Well, that is not the case. To keep thing simple, imagine that there is *another* constructor which takes `int` as:

```
 template<typename T>
 struct X 
 {
     X(T data) {}
     X(int data) {} //another constructor
 };
```

Now what `T` should be deduced to, when I write `f(10)`? Well, `T` could *any* type.

Note that there could be many other such cases. Take this specialization, for instance:

```
 template<typename T>
 struct X<T*>         //specialized for pointers
 {
    X(int data) {}; 
 };
```

Now what `T` should be deduced to for the call `f(10)`? Now it seems even harder.

It is therefore non-deducible context, which explains why your code doesn't work for `std::function` which is an identical case — just looks complex at the surface. Note that *lambdas* are not of type `std::function` — they're basically instances of compiler generated classes (i.e they're functors of *different* types than `std::function`).

Comment: Isn't the case with f (10); the same as the case with struct X x (10) ?
In both cases there is (should be) template argument deduction.

Also, the case with  X(int data) {} //another constructor doesn't even compile when we use struct X x (10) , because ‘X<T>::X(int) [with T = int]’ cannot be overloaded with ‘X<T>::X(T) [with T = int]’

Comment: @Nuclear: `struct X x (10);` will not compile (in pre c++17) because *template argument deduction* works for function template (or constructor template), not for class template.

Answer (score 5):

If we have:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
int myfunc(std::function<R(T)> lambda)
{
  return lambda(2);
}

int r = myfunc([](int i) { return i + 1; });
```

It will not compile.
But if you previously declare:

```
template <typename Func, typename Arg1>
static auto getFuncType(Func* func = nullptr, Arg1* arg1 = nullptr) -> decltype((*func)(*arg1));

template <typename Func>
int myfunc(Func lambda)
{
  return myfunc<int, decltype(getFuncType<Func, int>())>(lambda);
}
```

You can call your function with a lambda parameter without problem.

There are 2 new pieces of code here.

First, we have a function declaration which is only useful to return
   an old-style function pointer type, based on given template
   parameters:

```
template <typename Func, typename Arg1>
static auto getFuncType(Func* func = nullptr, Arg1* arg1 = nullptr) -> decltype((*func)(*arg1)) {};
```

Second, we have a function that takes a template argument to build our expected lambda type calling 'getFuncType':

```
template <typename Func>
int myfunc(Func lambda)
{
  return myfunc<int, decltype(getFuncType<Func, int>())>(lambda);
}
```

With the correct template parameters, now we can call the real 'myfunc'.
Complete code will be:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
int myfunc(std::function<R(T)> lambda)
{
  return lambda(2);
}

template <typename Func, typename Arg1>
static auto getFuncType(Func* func = nullptr, Arg1* arg1 = nullptr) -> decltype((*func)(*arg1)) {};

template <typename Func>
int myfunc(Func lambda)
{
  return myfunc<int, decltype(getFuncType<Func, int>())>(lambda);
}

int r = myfunc([](int i) { return i + 1; });
```

You can declare any overload for 'getFuncType' to match your lambda parameter. For example:

```
template <typename Func, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
static auto getFuncType(Func* func = nullptr, Arg1* arg1 = nullptr, Arg2* arg2 = nullptr) -> decltype((*func)(*arg1, *arg2)) {};
```

Comment: let me note that I learned this from: Boolinq project [link](https://github.com/k06a/boolinq)