# Cannot inititialize std::function implicitly

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I've written this functor to perform an *and* operation (*&&*):

```
// unary functor; performs '&&'
template <typename T>
struct AND
{
    function<bool (const T&)> x;
    function<bool (const T&)> y;

    AND(function<bool (const T&)> xx, function<bool (const T&)> yy) 
             : x(xx), y(yy) {}
    bool operator() ( const T &arg ) { return x(arg) && y(arg); }
};

// helper
template <typename T>
AND<T> And(function<bool (const T&)> xx, function<bool (const T&)> yy)
{
    return AND<T>(xx,yy);
}
```

**Note** it's constructor argument types:  `function<bool (const T&)>`.

Now, I am trying to instantiate it in various ways (inside `big_odd_exists()`):

```
int is_odd(int n) { return n%2; }
int is_big(int n) { return n>5; }


bool big_odd_exists( vector<int>::iterator first, vector<int>::iterator last ) 
{
    function<bool (const int &)> fun1 = is_odd;
    function<bool (const int &)> fun2 = is_big;

    return any_of( first, last, And( fun1, fun2 ) );  // instantiating an And object
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> n = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11};

    cout << "exists : " << big_odd_exists( n.begin(), n.end() ) << endl;
}
```

To my surprise, none of the implicit instantiations of the `std::functions` would compile.

Here are the cases I've tried (g++-4.8):

#### This compiles (*explicit* instantiation of a `std::function` object):

```
function<bool (const int &)> fun1 = is_odd;
function<bool (const int &)> fun2 = is_big;

return any_of( first, last, And( fun1, fun2 ) );
```

#### This does **not** compile (*implicit* instantiation of a temporary `std::function` object):

```
return any_of( first, last, And( is_odd, is_big ) );   // error: no matching function for call to ‘And(int (&)(int), int (&)(int))’
```

#### This compiles (*explicit* instantiation of a `std::function` object):

```
function<bool (const int &)> fun1 = bind(is_odd,_1);
function<bool (const int &)> fun2 = bind(is_big,_1);

return any_of( first, last, And(fun1, fun2) );
```

#### This does **not** compile (*implicit* instantiation of a temporary `std::function` object):

```
return any_of( first, last, And(bind(is_odd,_1), bind(is_big,_1)) );  // error: no matching function for call to ‘And(std::_Bind_helper<false, int (&)(int), const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type, std::_Bind_helper<false, int (&)(int), const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type)’
```

As far as I understand, the `std::functions` do *not* have explicit constructors.
So, why can't I use the *nicer to read* versions of the calls?

I have all the test cases in:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ded6cad4cab07541

Comment: Check the return type of the functions `is_big` and `is_odd`, and compare with that of the `std::function` objects you try to create.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : they return an `int` and I'm trying to create a `function<bool (const int &)>`. So, what's the problem with `int` as an argument?

Comment: A function returning an `int` can never be the same as a function returning a `bool`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yeap, you're right. Unfortunately, this makes no difference, as even if I define `is_odd` as `bool is_odd(const int &)`, the compiler cannot deduce what type `T` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest not abusing `std::function` and taking normal generic parameters instead. Treat `std::function` as a type-erased *container* for callable objects of a particular signature (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11629125/46642 for more details).

```
// unary functor; performs '&&'
template <typename X, typename Y>
struct AND
{
    X x;
    Y y;

    template <typename XX, typename YY>
    AND(XX&& xx, YY&& yy) 
             : x(std::forward<XX>(xx)), y(std::forward<YY>(yy)) {}

    template <typename T>
    auto operator() ( const T &arg ) -> decltype(x(arg) && y(arg))
    { return x(arg) && y(arg); }
};

template <typename T>
using Decay = typename std::decay<X>::type;

// helper
template <typename X, typename Y>
AND<Decay<X>, Decay<Y>> And(X&& xx, Y&& yy)
{
    return AND<Decay<X>, Decay<Y>>(std::forward<X>(xx), std::forward<Y>(yy));
}
```

Comment: @GrimFandango your comment `// won't compile` is... wrong? As can be seen in the page you linked to, it compiles and runs properly.

Comment: @Martinho: This templated operator() is what I needed. Thanks for that! I've re-created a simplified version of your solution in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/835af28ac3d18e72 . I'm in C++0x, so can't use &&. Instead I pass everything by value. Looking at your solution though, I can't understand what the need for `std::decay` is. I can't find anything in *Josuttis*'s book. By looking at the cppreference.com, I understand that if the template argument is a function, it removes `&` and adds `*` to it. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: It also removes `&` if it is something like `foo&`. Basically `decay` simulates pass-by-value semantics, and I used it because I want `And` to always store the function objects by value and not by reference.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that there's no way to deduce `T` in this context. Let's look at it from the compiler's perspective:

```
template <typename T>
AND<T> And(function<bool (const T&)> xx, function<bool (const T&)> yy)

// Later, invoked as:
And( is_odd, is_big )
```

"Hm, no `T` is specified on the call, I will have to deduce it. What's the argument? `is_odd`, which is decayed to type `int (*)(int)`. Now, I would have to instantiate `std::function<bool (const T&)>` for *all possible `T`* values and see for which/if any it can be constructed from type `int (*)(int)`. Well, there's infinitely many of them. Not gonna do this."

It would work if you specified the `T` tempalte argument explicitly:

```
return any_of( first, last, And<int>( is_odd, is_big ) );
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/0wiY4c)

---

Note that this holds even if you changed `is_odd` and `is_big` to match the `function` signature exactly (returning `bool` and taking `const int&`). It's the deduction that's the problem.

Comment: It wouldn't even help if the compiler would instantiate all templates, as the result would still be ambiguous. With an additional overload  `template<typename R, typename A> AND<A> And(R (*xx)(A), R (*yy)(A))` you wouldn't even need an explicit template argument. The real problem is discarding the type of the arguments too soon.