# Is there performance loss if change template parameter from function pointer to std::function?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, function-pointers, std-function

Function object could be any of the 3 : lambda expression, functor (classes overloaded operator ()), and std::function.

I understand that in a template, if a parameter type is defined as std::function, it could take parameter of any of the three.

for example, a type defined by `typedef std::function<bool(Logger&)> FilterStdFunction;` will be more general than 
`typedef bool(*FilterFunctionPointer)(Logger&);` when used as a template parameter.

But would there be performance loss? such as impossible to inline it?

Comment: Yes. No inlining, mandatory dynamic dispatch, and possibly dynamic allocation.

Comment: @KerrekSB could you pls give more reason for that or quote some source explaining the details a bit more?

Comment: Before using `std::function<type_dependent_on_type_parameter>` [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11628765/1012936)

Comment: @athos: well, think about what `std::function` does, and how you would necessarily need to structure it.

Comment: @kerrecksb std function *can* be inlined, it is just harder.

Comment: @athos have a very simple program and a great compiler who devirtualizes and inlines the function pointers?

Comment: ok... depending on vendor..