# C++ variadic template std::function to lambda conversion not working

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

I have the following code (simplified):

```
#include <functional>
template <typename... Args> void Callback(std::function<void(Args...)> f){
    // store f and call later
}
int main(){
    Callback<int, float>([](int a, float b){
        // do something
    });
}
```

The goal of this is to take some extra parameters, send off a packet, handle the response and call the lambda with the results
The issue with this is, it doesnt take the lambda.

```
# g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘Callback(main()::<lambda(int, float)>)’
test.cpp:8:3: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:2:34: note: template<class ... Args> void Callback(std::function<void(Args ...)>)
test.cpp:2:34: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:8:3: note:   ‘main()::<lambda(int, float)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<void(Args ...)>’
```

Is there any way to get this to work without going through the hassle of wrapping the lambda explicitly in a std::function?

```
Callback(std::function<void(int, float)>([](int a, float b){
    // do something
}));
```

Works flawlessly, even when omitting the Callback template arguments (like shown here).
There is still the 'extra' std::function though.

Why cant it figure out the conversion on its own? It works for non-templates:

```
void B(std::function<void(int, float)> f){/* ... */};
int main(){
    B([](int a, float b){
        // do something
    });
}
```

For reference, I'm using

> gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

Comment: Just because a lambda is *convertible to* an `std::function` doesn't mean it *is* an `std::function`. How is the compiler supposed to figure out the `std::function` template arguments from an unrelated type?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13358672/241631) answer your question? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9998402/241631)?

Comment: @Praetorian: It's able to do that just fine if the function does not contain template arguments (as described), so it should (i'd think) work for that case too

Comment: Template argument deduction *is* where it's going awry, so of course it works if you take that out of the equation. Read the answers I linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **dedicated cast**. Once you have a tool like this

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct memfun_type
{
    using type = void;
};

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct memfun_type<Ret(Class::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

template<typename F>
typename memfun_type<decltype(&F::operator())>::type
FFL(F const &func)
{ // Function from lambda !
    return func;
}
```

you can say `FFL()` to all lambda types to have them converted to what would be the correct version of `std::function`

```
int main()
{
    Callback(FFL([](int a, float b){
        // do something
    }));

    return 0;
}
```

[Display](http://ideone.com/omrRr9)

Answer (score 2):

As [Praetorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241631/praetorian) pointed out: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13358672/241631) answers my question. 
I'm really baffled why you need to use suck a hack though.
Code for reference:

```
#include <functional>
template <typename T> struct identity
{
  typedef T type;
};
template <typename... Args> void Callback(typename identity<std::function<void(Args...)>>::type f){
    // store f and call later
}
int main(){
    Callback<int, float>([](int a, float b){
        // do something
    });
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

When the lambda is non-capturing, you could use:

```
template <typename L> void Callback(L l){
    using F = typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(+l)>::type;
    std::function<F> f( l );
    // store f and call later
}
```

which allows you to call:

```
Callback([](int a, float b){
    // do something
});
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9345fcd7f1b0e9a)