# c++ template argument match std::function with function pointer

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I have a function wrapper that takes a function and a list of arguments and calls the function with those arguments:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
R wrapper(std::function<R(Args...)> f, Args... args) {
    auto ret = f(args...);
    return ret;
}
```

But the following does nott compile:

```
int f1(int a, int b) { return a+b; }

wrapper(f1, 1, 2);
```

It says:

> mismatched types ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>’ and ‘int (*)(int, int)’

However, if I do:

```
wrapper(std::function<int(int, int)>(f1), 5, 10);
```

...it will be well-formed, which is contradictory with the compiler error.

Why doesn't the compiler accept the first version?

Demo trace: https://onlinegdb.com/rJWzZIQX4

Comment: There is no contradiction here. The compiler's telling you that `std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>` is not the same type as `int (*)(int, int)` (and that it's not allowed to implicitly convert the latter to the former). In your second example, you explicitly convert it so the compiler is happy.

Comment: FWIW, in C++17 `std::function<int(int, int)>(f1)` can be shortened to `std::function{f1}` to save you some typing and repeating.

Comment: @StoryTeller Hm, that doesn't work for me: `candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<int (type-parameter-0-1...)>' against 'int (*)(int, int)'`

Comment: Also highly related and also tells you why lambdas also have this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998402/c11-does-not-deduce-type-when-stdfunction-or-lambda-functions-are-involved

Comment: @lubgr - Interesting. I would have thought that with the types deduced/specified this should be enough. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

When deducing template parameters, the compiler does not perform any conversions. Hence, in

```
wrapper(f1, 1, 2);
```

you are requesting the implicit construction of `std::function<int(int, int)>` from a function pointer of type `int (*)(int, int)`. When explicitly passing `std::function<int(int, int>(f1)`, there is no need for converting the argument, and the argument deduction works out.