# Auto deduce template types (w/ lambda)

Tags: c++, templates

I've created the following helper function:

```cpp
template<typename K1, typename V1, typename K2, typename V2>
[[nodiscard]] extern std::map<K2, V2> transform(const std::map<K1, V1> &map, std::function<std::pair<K2, V2>(K1, V1)> &&function) {
    std::map<K2, V2> transformedMap{};
    for (auto const &[k, v] : map) {
        auto pair = function(k, v);
        transformedMap.insert_or_assign(pair->first, pair->second);
    }
    return std::move(transformedMap);
}
```

Using it requires that I explicitly declare all types:

```cpp
auto mapped = transform<std::string, std::any, std::string, std::string>(map, [](const std::string &key, const std::any &value) {
    return std::make_pair(key, std::any_cast<std::string>(value));
});
```

Is there any way for the compiler to deduce the types so that I can write:

```cpp
auto mapped = transform(map, [](const std::string &key, const std::any &value) {
    return std::make_pair(key, std::any_cast<std::string>(value));
});
```

Comment: Template deduction can't be done with `std::function` using lambdas (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998673/1678770). However you don't really _need_ `std::function` here at all; you could just take a deduce `Fn` type template argument that satisfies the [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) trait with SFINAE (C++17) or the [`std::invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) concept with constraitns (C++20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template deduction can't be done with `std::function` using lambdas (see also [C++11 does not deduce type when std::function or lambda functions are involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998673/1678770)).

However you don't really *need* `std::function` here at all; you could just take `function` as a deduced template type-template argument, and then you can constrain it, and use `auto` to deduce the converted return type.

You just need to determine what `K2` and `V2` are based on the result of the function -- the result of which can be detected with the trait [`std::invoke_result_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of). How you determine what `K2` and `V2` are is up to you -- but it can be quite easy if you choose to assume that `function` will always return some form of `std::pair` object, since you can just access the `first_type` and `second_type` from it.

Realistically, you can make this part as complex as you want; for example, you could use `std::tuple_element_t` or something if you wanted to support any abstract pair/tuple-like type. For simplicity I will only demonstrate the former though.

If you have access to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) this can be solved with the [`std::invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) concept:

```cpp
#include <concepts>    // for std::invocable
#include <type_traits> // for std::invoke_result_t

template<typename K, typename V, typename Fn>
[[nodiscard]] 
auto transform(const std::map<K, V> &map, Fn&& function)
  requires(std::invocable<Fn,K,V>)
 {
    using pair_type = std::invoke_result_t<Fn,K,V>;
    using first_type = typename pair_type::first_type;
    using second_type = typename pair_type::second_type;
    
    auto transformedMap = std::map<first_type, second_type>{};
    for (auto const &[k, v] : map) {
        auto pair = function(k, v);
        transformedMap.insert_or_assign(pair.first, pair.second);
    }
    return transformedMap;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cqGcEs5df)</kbd>

If you don't have access to C++20, then the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) solution would be to use SFINAE with [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable):

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if, std::is_invocable

template<typename K, typename V, typename Fn,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Fn,K,V>>>
[[nodiscard]] 
... the rest is the same ...
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a3s6P7rj1)</kbd>

---

**Note:** Don't `std::move` on return values -- this is a pessimization that will [prevent optimizations like copy-elision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17473874/1678770).